# Connecting to SQL Server database on same server as website: localhost or ip adress?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This might be a pretty simple question, but if there really is a difference, it can make a huge impact on the performance :)

I have a dedicated server hosting my websites and my MSSQL databases.

So here it goes:
Will the performance on the website be better using localhost connecting to the MSSQL database instead of fx. mssql.domain.com (or direct ip adress) ?? :)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers :)
Because there is no performance effect I will be using the mssql.domain.com solution. Then it will be easier for me when creating the site on my laptops IIS-server and moving it over to the servers IIS-server. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using either will not make a difference. But localhost is preferable due to the following:
1 if the ip address changes in the future there will be changes to the code/config file

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't make a difference.

If you have dev/test/prod servers it might make your life easier if you can just specify localhost instead of changing the server name with each new environment, but it won't affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

No difference whatsoever.

So long as the three resolve to the same SQL server instance and use the same route.

Answer (score 1):

Localhost is your best bet, because if you use a IP PHP has to start a new thread and stuff.
It's also a plus if you have a dynamic IP or have it changed.